# change input position using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hi i have this html code

```
<div class='moves'>
    <div class='element'><input type='text' value='55' /></div>
    <input class='top' type='text' />
    <input class='Bottom' type='text' />
    <input class='left' type='text' />
    <input class='right' type='text' />
</div>
<div class='moves'>
    <div class='element'><input type='text' value='55' /></div>
    <input class='top' type='text' />
    <input class='Bottom' type='text' />
    <input class='left' type='text' />
    <input class='right' type='text' />
</div>
<div class='moves'>
    <div class='element'><input type='text' value='55' /></div>
    <input class='top' type='text' />
    <input class='Bottom' type='text' />
    <input class='left' type='text' />
    <input class='right' type='text' />
</div>
```

now what i want is when someone keyup inside `top` or `bottom` or `left` or `right` classes  change the div at same parent position to the values or top left buttom right ect so i tried this

```
$(".top").keyup(function(){
    var element = $(this).parent().closest('.element');
    console.log(element);
})
```

i gat this message

```
w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
```

but what i want is to change position to the input with value 55 
thanks a lot

Comment: `var element = $(this).siblings('.element');` or `var element = $(this).parent().find('.element');` or `var element = $(this).prevAll('.element');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest()` moves up (parent, parent of parent, ...), to find the element in children you should use `find`:

```
var element = $(this).parent().find('.element');
```

you also can use:

```
var element = $(this).siblings('.element');
```